# Can I simulate an http error in php and use .htaccess to route to a custom error page?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm trying to throw a http error through php code, using

```
http_response_code(403);
```

It works,the browser pops chrome`s forbidden error message.

But I do have a .htaccess file that should be routing the error to my custom error page, "/403.html".

The override works, if I attempt to access a forbidden file, but will not work if I throw the error through the http_response_code(403) function... Is there something I`m missing? Shouldn`t it work like that?

I'm testing in a XAMPP in windows

Comment: By _“.htaccess file that should be routing the error to my custom error page”_ you are referring to the `ErrorDocument` directive, yes? No, it should not work this way. That only works on 403 error situations that Apache has determined by itself. Once the request has been handed over to PHP though, it is PHP’s responsibility to take care of _all_ aspects of the response. Whatever document / response body you want to be returned together with that 403 status code, must be created / output by your PHP script now.

Comment: The easiest way to achieve that would probably be to just have PHP read the contents of your error document and pass it on, `readfile('/correct/file-system/path/to/your/403.html');` Make sure to prevent any further script execution by `exit;` or `die();` afterwards.